# Catch exception from external windows command utility

Tags: powershell, exception

I'm trying to terminate a script when running an external command results in an error. Consider this simple code:

```
try {
    where.exe Test-App
}

catch {
    Write-Error "Exception caught." -ErrorAction Continue
    throw
}

Write-Host "Test message!"
```

Output:

```
where.exe : INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
At line:2 char:5
    where.exe Test-App
...
Test message!
```

Is it possible to enter the catch block and throw, when an external command results in an error?

Desired output:

```
C:\Scripts\Test-Script.ps1 : Exception caught.
```

Comment: `If ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { <# do stuff #> }`

Comment: Alternatively, I think setting `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` will also result in thrown errors from external utilities (not 100% on that)

Comment: A third option: using `$myvar = Start-Process -FilePath 'where.exe' -ArgumentList 'test-app' -PassThru -Wait` and checking `$myvar.ExitCode` for non-zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [TheIncorrigible1 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496519/catch-exception-from-external-windows-command-utility/49496791#comment85997145_49496519), inspect `$LASTEXITCODE`, like so:

```
$where = where.exe test 2>&1
if($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0){
    throw "Exception caught."
    return
}
# otherwise continue, grab actual output from $where
```

Comment: Your `return` is never reached

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That depends entirely on the value of `$ErrorActionPreference` in the calling scope - hence the `return`, to ensure "soft termination" if you will :)

Comment: Doesn't `throw` *always* terminate?  As an aside, I think I've spent too much time away from pwsh lately

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 [Not _always_](https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/bfe1cbc30d1605fd52abdc9f13124375) - anyways, get back on that horse my friend! :)