# How I can export to txt any message from external Google GAM command from powershell

Tags: powershell, google-api, active-directory

I'm new into PowerShell and I'd like know how to read a output message from Google GAM into a text log file in c:/mygam.log
Here is an screenshot to help.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6dqY.png)

In fact I want export all message from GAM including this error message (red message)

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have access to the tool you are using, I can only speculate, but trying running the command like this:

```
. C:\GAMADV-XTD3\gam.exe create user username@domain.com firstname "A1ex" 1astname "H" password "PasswwOrd!" 2>&1 | Tee-Object -FilePath "path\to\google.log"
```

I would exclude the convertto-html part and see if outputting the information from the command directly works.  Also, I want to mention that the try/catch block the way you have written it will never actually work.  Try/catch only works if the error that occurs in the "try" block is a terminating error, which just won't happen if you are running external application.

Comment: excellent, I found the answer in this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49496519/catch-exception-from-external-windows-command-utility/49496791#comment85997145_49496519). That is the same that your purpose . It's work